# Exporting data to excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel

I want to execute some stored procedure and I want to export that result to Excel. How can Do that ? I'm new to SQL. any help or tutorials about this will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the 3 ways posted in the previous answer, or you can do it in plain sql, using [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) or [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx).

Some examples:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\DataFolder\Documents\TestExcel.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 5.0')...[Sheet1$] ;

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\TEST.xls;HDR=YES',
'select * from [Sheet1$]');
```

Both SSIS and SSRS import/export methods can't be done too easily, though they have the advantage of being able to automate their execution, and the copy from SSMS output is only a manual solution. The OPENROWSET/OPENDATASOURCE functions can be called more easily in a procedure or ad-hoc query.

Comment: +1 i refered [http://geekswithblogs.net/nagendraprasad/archive/2009/03/26/export-sql-server-data-into-excel.aspx] link but im getting error of  `The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.
`

Comment: I think that ACE.OLEDB is for MS Access, not sure if it's the same as for MS Excel. The old provider was JET, but not sure about last versions of Office. Anyway, following your error you could probably find help on the following pages: [link1](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/), [link2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/exceldev/thread/0f03c2de-3ee2-475f-b6a2-f4efb97de302), [link3](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-error-with-vista-64bit/).

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways that I know of

- Run procedure in ssms, then copy results into excel (make sure to turn on the option to copy column headers in tools,options,query results)
- Create a SQL server integration services (SSIS) package to run the procedure and write the results to a CDC or excel file.
- If you have SQL server reporting services (SSRS) you can create a report to run the procedure and display the results, then from the report website you can export the report to excel/csv. This can also be scheduled through SSRS subscriptions.

Comment: i refered [http://geekswithblogs.net/nagendraprasad/archive/2009/03/26/export-sql-server-data-into-excel.aspx] link but im getting error of  `The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.
`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global temp table like ##result and insert the result of the proc into it, then you could use the stored proc here https://github.com/hossamaladdin/ExportToExcel to export the data directly to Excel without any headaches like this:

```
drop table if exists ##mytable;
create table ##mytable(col1 varchar(100),col2 varchar(100))

 insert into ##mytable(col1,col2)
 exec sp_mystoredproc

 exec dbo.ExportToExcel 
 @tablename= '##mytable'
 ,@filepath = 'c:\myfolder\'
 ,@filename = 'Excelfile.xlsx'
```

after execution, the proc will display the file location and you could easily access it.

PS: you could also use parameter `@AttachToMail` and `@MailList` to
send the file directly to your email, but you'll need to enable db_mail first from SQL Server